# Random TimeoutException in Infinispan Hibernate L2 cache when put a load

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, infinispan

I am using Infinispan as a hibernate L2 cache. In a normal load system running without an issue. But when load put into the system the following exception was thrown from the cache cluster. Even though this not causing a functional impact reporting an ERROR seems a problem.

Infinispan version : 5.3

More info about the test : This hibernate L2 cache cluster had four nodes. During the test I didn't update the cache (Entities in the cache didn't update). Among four nodes two nodes heavily used the cache. But mostly I have seen this error in other two nodes.

**Error log**

```
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [remote-thread-0] org.infinispan.interceptors.CallInterceptor - Executing command: RemoveCommand{key=MarshalledValue{instance=<serialized>, serialized=ByteArray{size=1267, array=0x0301fe0409000000..}, cachedHashCode=1519}@ac27701, value=null, flags=[SKIP_CACHE_LOAD, SKIP_REMOTE_LOOKUP], ignorePreviousValue=false}.
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [remote-thread-0] org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveCommand - Nothing to remove since the entry is null or we have a null entry
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [remote-thread-0] org.infinispan.remoting.rpc.RpcManagerImpl - cosmos-db2-30512 invoking RemoveCommand{key=MarshalledValue{instance=<serialized>, serialized=ByteArray{size=1267, array=0x0301fe0409000000..}, cachedHashCode=1519}@ac27701, value=null, flags=[SKIP_CACHE_LOAD, SKIP_REMOTE_LOOKUP], ignorePreviousValue=false} to recipient list null with options RpcOptions{timeout=20000, unit=MILLISECONDS, fifoOrder=true, totalOrder=false, responseFilter=null, responseMode=SYNCHRONOUS, skipReplicationQueue=false}
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [remote-thread-0] org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport - dests=null, command=SingleRpcCommand{cacheName='Order', command=RemoveCommand{key=MarshalledValue{instance=<serialized>, serialized=ByteArray{size=1267, array=0x0301fe0409000000..}, cachedHashCode=1519}@ac27701, value=null, flags=[SKIP_CACHE_LOAD, SKIP_REMOTE_LOOKUP], ignorePreviousValue=false}}, mode=SYNCHRONOUS, timeout=20000
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [remote-thread-0] org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher - Replication task sending SingleRpcCommand{cacheName='Order', command=RemoveCommand{key=MarshalledValue{instance=<serialized>, serialized=ByteArray{size=1267, array=0x0301fe0409000000..}, cachedHashCode=1519}@ac27701, value=null, flags=[SKIP_CACHE_LOAD, SKIP_REMOTE_LOOKUP], ignorePreviousValue=false}} to single recipient cosmos-db2-29372 with response mode GET_ALL
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [remote-thread-0] org.infinispan.marshall.AdaptiveBufferSizePredictor - Next predicted buffer size for object type 'org.infinispan.commands.remote.SingleRpcCommand' will be 1536
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [remote-thread-0] org.infinispan.marshall.VersionAwareMarshaller - Wrote version 510
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.marshall.jboss.AbstractJBossMarshaller - Start unmarshaller after retrieving marshaller from thread local
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.marshall.VersionAwareMarshaller - Read version 510
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [remote-thread-0] org.infinispan.marshall.AdaptiveBufferSizePredictor - Next predicted buffer size for object type 'org.infinispan.commands.remote.SingleRpcCommand' will be 512
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.marshall.jboss.AbstractJBossMarshaller - Start unmarshaller after retrieving marshaller from factory
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.marshall.VersionAwareMarshaller - Read version 510
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.marshall.jboss.AbstractJBossMarshaller - Stop unmarshaller
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [remote-thread-0] org.infinispan.marshall.VersionAwareMarshaller - Wrote version 510
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.marshall.jboss.AbstractJBossMarshaller - Stop unmarshaller
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher - Attempting to execute command: SingleRpcCommand{cacheName='Order', command=PutKeyValueCommand{key=MarshalledValue{instance=<serialized>, serialized=ByteArray{size=1267, array=0x0301fe0409000000..}, cachedHashCode=1519}@545404b2, value=MarshalledValue{instance=<serialized>, serialized=ByteArray{size=2022, array=0x0301fe0409000000..}, cachedHashCode=1103892469}@40c6375, flags=[ZERO_LOCK_ACQUISITION_TIMEOUT, FORCE_ASYNCHRONOUS, SKIP_CACHE_LOAD, SKIP_REMOTE_LOOKUP, PUT_FOR_EXTERNAL_READ], putIfAbsent=true, metadata=EmbeddedMetadata{version=null}, successful=true}} [sender=cosmos-db2-29372]
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [remote-thread-0] org.infinispan.marshall.jboss.AbstractJBossMarshaller - Stop marshaller
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [remote-thread-0] org.infinispan.marshall.jboss.AbstractJBossMarshaller - Stop marshaller
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.remoting.InboundInvocationHandlerImpl - Calling perform() on SingleRpcCommand{cacheName='Order', command=PutKeyValueCommand{key=MarshalledValue{instance=<serialized>, serialized=ByteArray{size=1267, array=0x0301fe0409000000..}, cachedHashCode=1519}@545404b2, value=MarshalledValue{instance=<serialized>, serialized=ByteArray{size=2022, array=0x0301fe0409000000..}, cachedHashCode=1103892469}@40c6375, flags=[ZERO_LOCK_ACQUISITION_TIMEOUT, FORCE_ASYNCHRONOUS, SKIP_CACHE_LOAD, SKIP_REMOTE_LOOKUP, PUT_FOR_EXTERNAL_READ], putIfAbsent=true, metadata=EmbeddedMetadata{version=null}, successful=true}}
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.commands.remote.BaseRpcInvokingCommand - Invoking command PutKeyValueCommand{key=MarshalledValue{instance=<serialized>, serialized=ByteArray{size=1267, array=0x0301fe0409000000..}, cachedHashCode=1519}@545404b2, value=MarshalledValue{instance=<serialized>, serialized=ByteArray{size=2022, array=0x0301fe0409000000..}, cachedHashCode=1103892469}@40c6375, flags=[ZERO_LOCK_ACQUISITION_TIMEOUT, FORCE_ASYNCHRONOUS, SKIP_CACHE_LOAD, SKIP_REMOTE_LOOKUP, PUT_FOR_EXTERNAL_READ], putIfAbsent=true, metadata=EmbeddedMetadata{version=null}, successful=true}, with originLocal flag set to false
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor - Invoked with command PutKeyValueCommand{key=MarshalledValue{instance=<serialized>, serialized=ByteArray{size=1267, array=0x0301fe0409000000..}, cachedHashCode=1519}@545404b2, value=MarshalledValue{instance=<serialized>, serialized=ByteArray{size=2022, array=0x0301fe0409000000..}, cachedHashCode=1103892469}@40c6375, flags=[ZERO_LOCK_ACQUISITION_TIMEOUT, FORCE_ASYNCHRONOUS, SKIP_CACHE_LOAD, SKIP_REMOTE_LOOKUP, PUT_FOR_EXTERNAL_READ], putIfAbsent=true, metadata=EmbeddedMetadata{version=null}, successful=true} and InvocationContext [org.infinispan.context.impl.NonTxInvocationContext@49559866]
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.marshall.jboss.AbstractJBossMarshaller - Marshallable type 'org.infinispan.marshall.MarshalledValue' known and is marshallable=true
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.marshall.jboss.AbstractJBossMarshaller - Marshallable type 'org.infinispan.marshall.MarshalledValue' known and is marshallable=true
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor - handleTopologyAffectedCommand for command PutKeyValueCommand{key=MarshalledValue{instance=<serialized>, serialized=ByteArray{size=1267, array=0x0301fe0409000000..}, cachedHashCode=1519}@545404b2, value=MarshalledValue{instance=<serialized>, serialized=ByteArray{size=2022, array=0x0301fe0409000000..}, cachedHashCode=1103892469}@40c6375, flags=[ZERO_LOCK_ACQUISITION_TIMEOUT, FORCE_ASYNCHRONOUS, SKIP_CACHE_LOAD, SKIP_REMOTE_LOOKUP, PUT_FOR_EXTERNAL_READ], putIfAbsent=true, metadata=EmbeddedMetadata{version=null}, successful=true}
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.NonTransactionalLockingInterceptor - Are (cosmos-db2-30512) we the lock owners for key 'MarshalledValue{instance=<serialized>, serialized=ByteArray{size=1267, array=0x0301fe0409000000..}, cachedHashCode=1519}@545404b2'? true
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.LockManagerImpl - Attempting to lock MarshalledValue{instance=<serialized>, serialized=ByteArray{size=1267, array=0x0301fe0409000000..}, cachedHashCode=1519}@545404b2 with acquisition timeout of 0 millis
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.containers.ReentrantPerEntryLockContainer - Timed out attempting to acquire lock for key MarshalledValue{instance=<serialized>, serialized=ByteArray{size=1267, array=0x0301fe0409000000..}, cachedHashCode=1519}@545404b2 after 0 milliseconds
2015-03-09 11:33:07 DEBUG [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.LockManagerImpl - Failed to acquire lock MarshalledValue{instance=<serialized>, serialized=ByteArray{size=1267, array=0x0301fe0409000000..}, cachedHashCode=1519}@545404b2, owner is Thread[remote-thread-0,5,main]
2015-03-09 11:33:07 DEBUG [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.LockManagerImpl - This transaction (Thread[Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512,5,main]) already owned locks []
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.marshall.jboss.AbstractJBossMarshaller - Start unmarshaller after retrieving marshaller from thread local
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.marshall.VersionAwareMarshaller - Read version 510
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.marshall.jboss.AbstractJBossMarshaller - Stop unmarshaller
2015-03-09 11:33:07 ERROR [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor - ISPN000136: Execution error
org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Unable to acquire lock after [0 milliseconds] on key [Order#1] for requestor [Thread[Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512,5,main]]! Lock held by [Thread[remote-thread-0,5,main]]
    at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.LockManagerImpl.lock(LockManagerImpl.java:214)
    at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.LockManagerImpl.acquireLockNoCheck(LockManagerImpl.java:197)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.lockKey(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:149)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.lockKey(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:145)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:83)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:134)
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:83)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.MarshalledValueInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(MarshalledValueInterceptor.java:154)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:83)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:134)
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:83)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.handleTopologyAffectedCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:216)
    at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.handleWriteCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:194)
    at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:83)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.CacheMgmtInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(CacheMgmtInterceptor.java:160)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:83)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:134)
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.IsMarshallableInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(IsMarshallableInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:83)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleAll(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:128)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleDefault(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:83)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.impl.ClassLoaderAwareCache$ClassLoaderAwareCommandInterceptor.handleDefault(ClassLoaderAwareCache.java:79)
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:83)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InterceptorChain.invoke(InterceptorChain.java:343)
    at org.infinispan.commands.remote.BaseRpcInvokingCommand.processVisitableCommand(BaseRpcInvokingCommand.java:61)
    at org.infinispan.commands.remote.SingleRpcCommand.perform(SingleRpcCommand.java:70)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.InboundInvocationHandlerImpl.handleInternal(InboundInvocationHandlerImpl.java:122)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.InboundInvocationHandlerImpl.handleWithWaitForBlocks(InboundInvocationHandlerImpl.java:205)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.InboundInvocationHandlerImpl.handle(InboundInvocationHandlerImpl.java:111)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.executeCommandFromLocalCluster(CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.java:281)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.handle(CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.java:233)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.RequestCorrelator.handleRequest(RequestCorrelator.java:460)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.RequestCorrelator.receiveMessage(RequestCorrelator.java:377)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.RequestCorrelator.receive(RequestCorrelator.java:247)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.MessageDispatcher$ProtocolAdapter.up(MessageDispatcher.java:667)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.up(JChannel.java:730)
    at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.up(ProtocolStack.java:1019)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.up(Protocol.java:409)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.RSVP.up(RSVP.java:221)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FRAG2.up(FRAG2.java:182)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:434)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:434)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.up(Protocol.java:409)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.SEQUENCER.up(SEQUENCER.java:270)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.up(Protocol.java:409)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STABLE.up(STABLE.java:294)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.removeAndDeliver(UNICAST3.java:792)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.handleDataReceived(UNICAST3.java:704)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.up(UNICAST3.java:382)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.up(NAKACK2.java:600)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.VERIFY_SUSPECT.up(VERIFY_SUSPECT.java:147)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FD_ALL.up(FD_ALL.java:184)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK.up(FD_SOCK.java:301)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.MERGE3.up(MERGE3.java:303)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.up(Discovery.java:379)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.passMessageUp(TP.java:1405)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TP$MyHandler.run(TP.java:1591)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-03-09 11:33:07 ERROR [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.remoting.InboundInvocationHandlerImpl - Exception executing command
org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Unable to acquire lock after [0 milliseconds] on key [Order#1] for requestor [Thread[Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512,5,main]]! Lock held by [Thread[remote-thread-0,5,main]]
    at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.LockManagerImpl.lock(LockManagerImpl.java:214)
    at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.LockManagerImpl.acquireLockNoCheck(LockManagerImpl.java:197)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.lockKey(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:149)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.lockKey(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:145)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:83)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:134)
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:83)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.MarshalledValueInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(MarshalledValueInterceptor.java:154)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:83)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:134)
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:83)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.handleTopologyAffectedCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:216)
    at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.handleWriteCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:194)
    at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:83)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.CacheMgmtInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(CacheMgmtInterceptor.java:160)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:83)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:134)
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.IsMarshallableInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(IsMarshallableInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:83)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleAll(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:128)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleDefault(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:83)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.impl.ClassLoaderAwareCache$ClassLoaderAwareCommandInterceptor.handleDefault(ClassLoaderAwareCache.java:79)
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:83)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InterceptorChain.invoke(InterceptorChain.java:343)
    at org.infinispan.commands.remote.BaseRpcInvokingCommand.processVisitableCommand(BaseRpcInvokingCommand.java:61)
    at org.infinispan.commands.remote.SingleRpcCommand.perform(SingleRpcCommand.java:70)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.InboundInvocationHandlerImpl.handleInternal(InboundInvocationHandlerImpl.java:122)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.InboundInvocationHandlerImpl.handleWithWaitForBlocks(InboundInvocationHandlerImpl.java:205)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.InboundInvocationHandlerImpl.handle(InboundInvocationHandlerImpl.java:111)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.executeCommandFromLocalCluster(CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.java:281)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.handle(CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.java:233)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.RequestCorrelator.handleRequest(RequestCorrelator.java:460)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.RequestCorrelator.receiveMessage(RequestCorrelator.java:377)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.RequestCorrelator.receive(RequestCorrelator.java:247)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.MessageDispatcher$ProtocolAdapter.up(MessageDispatcher.java:667)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.up(JChannel.java:730)
    at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.up(ProtocolStack.java:1019)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.up(Protocol.java:409)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.RSVP.up(RSVP.java:221)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FRAG2.up(FRAG2.java:182)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:434)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:434)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.up(Protocol.java:409)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.SEQUENCER.up(SEQUENCER.java:270)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.up(Protocol.java:409)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STABLE.up(STABLE.java:294)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.removeAndDeliver(UNICAST3.java:792)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.handleDataReceived(UNICAST3.java:704)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.up(UNICAST3.java:382)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.up(NAKACK2.java:600)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.VERIFY_SUSPECT.up(VERIFY_SUSPECT.java:147)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FD_ALL.up(FD_ALL.java:184)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK.up(FD_SOCK.java:301)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.MERGE3.up(MERGE3.java:303)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.up(Discovery.java:379)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.passMessageUp(TP.java:1405)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TP$MyHandler.run(TP.java:1591)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [Incoming-1,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.remoting.InboundInvocationHandlerImpl - Unable to execute command, got invalid response ExceptionResponse
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [OOB-4,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.marshall.jboss.AbstractJBossMarshaller - Start unmarshaller after retrieving marshaller from thread local
2015-03-09 11:33:07 TRACE [tid=cosmos-db2-150309112549721-1602836942-0-1] [OOB-4,cosmos-db2-30512] org.infinispan.marshall.VersionAwareMarshaller - Read version 510
```

**Hibernate L2 cache configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:5.1"
            xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:5.1 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-5.1.xsd">

    <global>
        <globalJmxStatistics enabled="true" cacheManagerName="H2L" jmxDomain="org.infinispan"
                             allowDuplicateDomains="true"/>
        <transport
                transportClass="org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport"
                clusterName="infinispan-hibernate-cluster"
                distributedSyncTimeout="50000"
                strictPeerToPeer="false">
            <properties>
                <property name="configurationFile" value="jgroups.xml"/>
            </properties>
        </transport>
    </global>

    <default>
    </default>

    <!-- entity/collection caching that uses replication -->
    <namedCache name="replicated-cache-entity">
        <clustering mode="replication">
            <stateTransfer fetchInMemoryState="false" timeout="20000"/>
            <sync replTimeout="20000"/>
        </clustering>
        <!-- In distributed mode, Infinispan will store every entry on a subset of the nodes in the cache cluster
            (controlled by the parameter numOwners, which controls how many owners each entry will have).
            Theoretically reducing number of copies should increase the performance. Better to do a test with
            mode distribution as well. -->
        <!--<clustering mode="distribution">-->
            <!--<sync replTimeout="20000"/>-->
            <!--<hash numOwners="2" rehashEnabled="true"/>-->
        <!--</clustering>-->
        <locking isolationLevel="READ_COMMITTED" concurrencyLevel="1000"
                 lockAcquisitionTimeout="15000" useLockStriping="false"/>
        <!-- Eviction configuration. WakeupInterval defines how often the eviction thread runs, in milliseconds.
0           means the eviction thread will never run. A separate executor is used for eviction in each cache. -->
        <!-- maxEntries should be fine tune depend on the entities used to caching. Right now caching the events there fore
             using a higher number -->
        <eviction maxEntries="1000" strategy="LRU"/>
        <expiration maxIdle="100000" wakeUpInterval="5000"/>
        <storeAsBinary enabled="true"/>
        <!--<transaction useSynchronization="true"
        transactionMode="TRANSACTIONAL" autoCommit="false"
        lockingMode="OPTIMISTIC"/>-->
    </namedCache>

  </infinispan>
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Forums crosslink: https://developer.jboss.org/message/920504?et=watches.email.thread#920504

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing really wrong with your configuration, these timeouts happen regularly under load (a lock has been contented and the request failed). Hibernate got an exception when calling cache.put() (or transaction.commit()) on the originating node and either handled that with retry or just did not cache this value.

And you're right that these regular situations shouldn't be reported as ERRORs.

Comment: In Infinispan configuration I have set lockAcquisitionTimeout="15000" but in the log it says "Unable to acquire lock after [0 milliseconds] on key ...". In the logs it seems ZERO_LOCK_ACQUISITION_TIMEOUT flag is on.  How this could happen ? Why it's not obey to config file ?

Comment: The flags are set by Hibernate using putForExternalRead() operations. See http://infinispan.org/docs/7.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_putforexternalread_operation for explanation.

Comment: In fact in this case, Hibernate did not get any exception, as I was suggesting in the answer - the operation fails silently in terms of propagated exceptions (regrettably not without logging an error).

Comment: I have updated the bug with more info. I can see error was reporting continuously. I wasn't update any cached entity during the test. So that not reason to call putForExternalRead() multiple times.  Also I can't see an evidence to call putForExternalRead()  from the log. I can see visitPutKeyValueCommand() in the log. I didn't find any resource to confirm Hibernate L2 cache use putForExternalRead() for cache inserts instead of put(). I am afraid to swallow the exception without having a clear picture.

Comment: As doc says, the entity is written to the cache after it's read from database. When two concurrent reads fail to find entity in L2 cache, they retrieve it from DB and the write it to the cache in this way - and one of them fails because it sees that the entry is already written. The evidence is PUT_FOR_EXTERNAL_READ flag in the command.

Comment: Thanks Flavius. Agree on putForExternalRead() command usage due to  PUT_FOR_EXTERNAL_READ flag. Can you please show me the evidence for "When two concurrent reads fail " and "one of them fails because it sees that the entry is already written" ? Also during the test I haven't updated the cache. So I doubt why it's fails to read from the cache. I can understand initial mis and some more misses if cluster fails. But without that failing to read from the cache is an issue. Also I am thinking to report a bug for Infinispan about the log level.

Comment: Oops, I have noticed only now that the previous logs are from thread Incoming-1 while the error is in Incoming-2. So, I don't have your logs, but you can try to find what happens on the key which was processed when you got the exception.

Comment: I'll try to find more logs relevant to Incoming-2 and then will update the original post.

Comment: And also to the possible other thread updating the key at the same time. Regrettably, you use some configuration that hides the keys, though sometimes the byte array version can be seen (the first three bytes in the byte array denote that it's String and its length, rest of it are UTF-8 bytes - you can show more using -Dinfinispan.arrays.debug=true)

Comment: I have updated the question with logs. I have a doubt why remote-thread-0 is executing RemoveCommand ? I'm not doing modifications to cache. It seems remote-thread-0 hold the lock when executing PUT_FOR_EXTERNAL_READ by Incoming-1. Appreciate your help.

Comment: If you have doubts why a remove is executed, you have to trace it back to sender and see the logs there. I am not an expert on Hibernate and I don't know in what situations it deletes the entry, but I'd trust that it does what needs to be done, unless you see that your application's behaviour is incorrect.

Comment: I can not see an issue in my app. Now I am trying to update the cache into Infinispan version 6. I want to stop this exception without swallowing it. Let me see whether this fixed in Infinispan version 6.

Comment: These exceptions should not be logged. As hinted in previous comments, these are putForExternalRead() calls, whose job is to cache data read from the database. Apart from upgrading to a later Hibernate + Infinispan combo to avoid the logging (see if it gets rid of it), you could also make sure that the entity cache has a bigger size for all the entities you are working with (and maybe increase expiration timeouts), so that hot data remains in the cache longer rather than being loaded from the database.

Answer (score 0):

TimeoutException is expected here and not to be considered a problem. So presumably nothing should be logged in ERROR level.

Here clustering mode use as 'replication' but it's generally not a recommended choice. I was able to overcome the issue by changing the clustering mode to 'invalidation'. This is a good choice hence my cache is a read-heavy. The 'invalidation' mode not work properly with hibernate-infinispan-4.1.19.Final (this is the version by default ship with Infinispan 5.3). hibernate-infinispan-4.2.18.Final version  works properly with 'invalidation' mode. By updating the hibernate-infinispan version managed to overcome the issue.